# Issues setting up concurrent Selenium webdriver calls on remote server

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver

when I run the following code on my personal computer, it runs fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def open_driver(num):
    options = webdriver.firefox.options.Options()
    options.headless = True
    print("Starting")
    with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
        pass
    print("Ending")
    return num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(6) as executor:
        results = executor.map(open_driver,list(range(6)))
    print(list(results))
```

Output:

```
StartingStarting

Starting
Starting
StartingStarting

Ending
Ending
Ending
Ending
Ending
Ending
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

However, when I try to run the same on a remote DigitalOcean server (running Ubuntu release 18.04), it produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multi_drive.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(list(results))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 586, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "multi_drive.py", line 24, in open_driver
    with webdriver.Firefox(options = options, executable_path = '/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/geckodriver') as browser:
  File "/home/ubuntu/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ubuntu/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/testing/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

I understand this issue is typically caused by incompatability between library versions, but I don't think this is the case here (Mozilla Firefox 74.0.1, geckodriver 0.26.0, selenium 3.141.0). I can start single webdriver instances in Python shell without error, and when I change the threadpool max_workers variable to:

```
 with ThreadPoolExecutor(1) as executor:
```

The program runs as intended (minus the concurrency):

```
Starting
Finally
Starting
Finally
Starting
Finally
Starting
Finally
Starting
Finally
Starting
Finally
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The program also runs **without** error when I set the pool count to 2, so some amount of concurrency appears possible (and max_workers = 6 runs fine for code without the webdriver call).

max_workers = 3 seems to be the threshold at which the program starts to fail.

(Unsure if relevant, but "cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max" here produces 7677)

Is this a constraint of the server? (Software or hardware?) How can I check? Otherwise, what on earth is happening here?? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.